# Why jquery mouseup event is not working in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

i am using this code to detect mouseup event on a div's scroller.This code is working fine in firefox 3/4/5 but not works in google chorme 12/10/5.

**Code:**

```
jQuery('#slideshow').scroll(function () { 


jQuery(this).mouseup(function(){
alert("hi it's a mouse up");
});

    });
```

in firefox it shows alert but in google chrome it is not showing any alert.

Please tell me the solution of this problem?

-Thanks in advance

Comment: if i use mousedown in same script then it's working fine in both browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/32fFR/3/)
It was a conflict with the mouseover in the bottom of the script.
Cause the `mouseover` was actually already 'stopping' the gallery.

Just removed the `mouseup` from the `.scroll() function` and added beneath where
we already have a mouseout listener:

```
$('#slideshow').bind('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
    if (e.type === 'mouseover') {
        clearTimeout(interv);
        $('#test').html('Stop on mouseover');
    } else {
        $('#slideshow').animate({scrollLeft: iw * (counter - 1)}, 1000);
        start();
    }
});
```

Comment: ya i researched over it and come to the conclusion that mouse up and scroll are in a race condition in chrome so it's better to use mouseover in my case

Comment: Race condition is the only reason i came to know

Comment: But still the reason for mouseup is not very much clear to me

Comment: Neither to me any more. That's why I removed it. ;)

Comment: UPDATE with a newer version (fixed minor bugs) http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/32fFR/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Slideshow</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    #slideshow
    {
        width:200px;
        padding:10px;
        height:200px;
        overflow:auto;
    }
.slide
{    
    height:100px;
    margin:20px 0px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slideshow">
<div class="slide">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="slide">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="slide">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="slide">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#slideshow').scroll(function() {
        jQuery(this).mouseup(function() {
            alert("hi it's a mouse up");
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I always recommend to use like Ghommey said

```
 jQuery(function($){
  $('#slideshow').scroll(function(){/*Do something, if need*/}).mouseup(function(){
     alert("hi it's a mouse up");
  });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

on results from peanut galleary

```
// Bad
$(window).mouseup(function() { ... });

// Good
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) { ... });
```